# Command in Xcode to rewrite array creation to use literal syntax

Tags: xcode, objective-c-literals

I watched a WWDC video and saw that there is a Refactor option in Xcode that -- boom -- can automatically update your whole code to use the new, more readable notation.

Rather than doing `[NSArray arrayWithObjects @"a",@"b",@"c",nil]`, e.g. , you simply do `@[@"a",@"b",@"c"]`

Where's the menu item in Xcode that will convert en masse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the target, Menu:Edit:Refactor:Convert to modern Objective-C Syntax.

[image]

Comment: If I do this, will I forgo IOS5?

Comment: Modern Objective-C Syntax is supported back to iOS 4.3, it is part of ARCLite.

Comment: ARCLite is only needed for subscripting. Collection literals, NSNumber literals, and boxed expressions are just syntactic sugar for old API, so you can deploy to any older OS version with those.